# Simple Java function to create an array

Tags: java, arrays, function

I am currently working on a program which performs several different functions, yet all on the same array (made up of the command-line arguments).

I am trying to create a function that will create an array. At the moment, I have to repeatedly put the following in each if statement of main() :

```
 final int N = args.length;    
 final long []a = new long [args.length];
 for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) 
   a[i] = Long.parseLong (args[i]);
```

Surely I can put this in a function that I can call within a single line, rather than using this over and over again?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to create a `static` function, so you are able to call it without creating a new instance of the object.

```
static long[] getValues(String[] args){
    long []a = new long [args.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) 
        a[i] = Long.parseLong (args[i]);
    return a;
}

void main(String[] args){
    long[] values = getValues(args); 
    //here you call the static function
    //do some code magic with those values
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you can add some texts and explain your code. In that way, more SO users can receive benefit. :)

Comment: Sure. Let me try to explain

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
public long[] methodName(String[] args){
    final int N = args.length;    
    final long[] a = new long [N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) 
        a[i] = Long.parseLong (args[i]);
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `System.arraycopy(args, 0, a, 0, args.length);`

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)